# How to call function inside the inner.html

Tags: javascript, html

This is my normal function in `JS` file. I need to `closeHomeScreenPopup`  function which is defined inside the `document.getElementById("addToHomeScreenPrompt").innerHTML`. I have passed `onclick` as string as you can see.

```
export default function register() {
  // Checks if should display install popup notification:
  if (isIos() && !isInStandaloneMode()) {
    function closeHomeScreenPopup() {
      console.log("jkjilkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlk");
    }
    document.getElementById("addToHomeScreenPrompt").innerHTML =
      '<div onclick="closeHomeScreenPopup()"><span class="plush--sign">+</span><p>Install the webapp on your iPhone:tap <img style="width: 20px; margin: 0 4px;" alt="" src="img/share_icon.png"/> and then Add to homescreen.</p></div>';
  }
}
```

But I get error when do `onclick` on the `div`

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: closeHomeScreenPopup is not defined
    at HTMLDivElement.onclick (temperature-schedule?roomId=2:51)
```

How can I call the `closeHomeScreenPopup` from inside `inner.html`

Comment: The function is not defined in your innerHTML. It's just attached to the onclick event handler. You must define the function itself globally.

Comment: Functions called from inline event listeners `onxxxx` must be in global window scope. Time to stop using inline listeners

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: @JaredSmith What is wrong with his binding? I agree it's not the cleanest but it works.

Comment: @MarkBaijens The main problem is his usage of inline javascript. The dupe proposed by Jared shows the correct way of doing things

Comment: @bambam Weather this is wrong or right is a matter of opinion and design. It's a good comment but no reason to mark his question as a duplicate of the linked question and not the cause of his direct problem.

Comment: Ooops!! I didn't get what you all are talking. But anyway thanks for the debate. I will surely try to understand that comments. And I think it is not a duplicate @JaredSmith **;-)**

Comment: @MarkBaijens Agreed (partially) :-) I would argue that his problem exists exclusively because of usage of technics used in 1998. I didn't mark as a dupe because of what you said though

Comment: @MarkBaijens I'm not trying to take a moral stance here. The OP is trying to add a click handler to a dynamically created DOM element. So it's a dupe IMO.

Comment: @JaredSmith I disagree, the function is successfully bound to the onclick event. The function that is bound couldn't be found because it's in the wrong scope. There is probably a duplicate for that too, but it's not the question you linked. The accepted answer of your linked question is even a jQuery solution which the OP doesn't even use.

Comment: @MarkBaijens plenty of pure JS solutions on that question further down. You can use your votes however you wish, you don't have to agree with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything in JS is bound to containing scope. Therefore, if you define a function directly in the *register* functions, it will not be bound to *window* object.

*closeHomeScreenPopup* function should be defined globally

```
 window[closeHomeScreenPopup] = function() {
      console.log("jkjilkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlk");
    }
```

```js
function closeHomeScreenPopup() {
  console.log("jkjilkjlkjlkjlkjlkjlk");
}
document.getElementById("addToHomeScreenPrompt").innerHTML =
  '<div onclick="closeHomeScreenPopup()"><span class="plush--sign">+</span><p>Install the webapp on your iPhone:tap <img style="width: 20px; margin: 0 4px;" alt="" src="img/share_icon.png"/> and then Add to homescreen.</p></div>';
```

```html
<div id="addToHomeScreenPrompt"></div>
```

Comment: While this "works" (or will once you fix the ReferenceError), it would be better to attach the handler in the relevant file rather than define a global.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you is not a good practice to pollute global object with functions :)